# HTTPWebResponse is returning an error number: 500

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to call my API reference but when it gets to the HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) section my code just returns the error 500. I'm unsure on what my code is actually missing as im pretty new to APIs
any help is appreciated.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"####");
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add($"USERNAME: {Username}, PASSWORD: {Password}");
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36";
                request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

                string responseFromServer = "";

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

                    using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                    }
```

Comment: 500 is a server error. The server crashed. You have to check the server logs to find out what's wrong. In any case all this code could be replaced with a single `HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url)`. In .NET Core `HttpWebRequest` is just a compatibility wrapper over HttpClient

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions asking for customer support with third-party services (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team.

Answer (score 0):

A [500 HTTP response](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) code is a server based error, your code is not the issue. However, some "poorly made" APIs do not handle insufficient keys with the proper HTTP codes, resulting in a server error due to the front end not sending the required keys/values in the request.

Good luck!